# How to extend a string literal type?

Tags: typescript

Given

```
export type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar;
```

How to extend the type `Foo` (in another module) to also allow `'x' | 'y'` as possible value?

If I write somewhere else:

```
export type Foo = 'x' | 'y'
```

Typescript complains about the duplicate identifier `Foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it is in a separate file you can simply rename the original foo as something else during import in the target file.

original.ts

```
export type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar';
```

target.ts

```
import { Foo as OriginalFoo } from './original';

export type Foo = OriginalFoo | 'x' | 'y';
```

now if you use the Foo definition from the target.ts file it should allow 'foo' or 'bar' or 'x' or 'y'

Answer (score 5):

You can't override the existing `Foo` type. The reason for this is that existing code can depend on `Foo` being *only* `'foo'` or `'bar'`. In the example below, the type checker not only infers that `a` cannot be `'foo'` in the `else` block, it can infer that `a` is definitely `'bar'` there:

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar';
function test(x: Foo) {
    if (x === 'foo') {
        // infers x === 'foo'
    } else {
        // infers x === 'bar'
    }
}
```

However, you can make a new type alias which accepts all values of the `Foo` type, plus some others:

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar';
type FooEx = Foo | 'x' | 'y';

var a : FooEx;
a = 'foo'; // ok
a = 'x';   // ok
a = 'z';   // error
```

Comment: Well, but there may be code that has an extension that extends the allowed of literal types. Suppose you use string literal types for events, then there can be extensions that add new events to the system. I think, the assumption unnecessary limiting that existing code *only* depends on `'foo`' or `'bar'`...

Answer (score 2):

From TypeScript Language Specification:

> An interface can have multiple merged declarations, but a type alias for an object type literal cannot.

Unfortunately, you cannot extend a type.