# Typescript: Is there a union of string literal types for the output of typeof?

Tags: typescript

I'm aware that the output type of typeof is a string.

In typescript there's this pattern, called a ["Union of string literal types"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types):

```js
export type Fruit = 'banana' | 'apple' | 'orange';
```

**Q: Is there an importable union of string literal types that exists in any library allowing one to ensure a field can only be a possible output of the typeof operator?**

Example psuedoish code:

```js
import {JSType} from '@somelib/types'; // <--- what I want, this is a bogus type/lib

export class SomeClass {
    data: any;
    type: JSType;
    constructor (params) {
        this.data = params.data;
        this.type = typeof params.data;
    }
    render = () => {
        switch(this.type){
            case 'boolean':
                // return checkbox html component
            // more type cases
            default:
                // return input html component
        }
    }
}
```

I could manually create the type I need, but I'd prefer to let someone smarter than me handle the maintenance of the type, and future proof if JS/TS ever adds some type besides 'string' | 'number' | 'function' | 'object' | 'undefined'.

Also, in a pinch if I need to add a custom type, then I can just [extend the existing type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492418/how-to-extend-a-string-literal-type/37492566), to include the strings I need.

**Edit #1:** Updated terminology. Thanks to jcalz

Comment: Terminology issue: you're not talking about a template literal type (you can tell because it's not surrounded by backticks); instead you mean a union of [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types)s.

Comment: thank you for clearing that up - I edited the post to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has to be a better way to do this, seeing as those definitions already exist somewhere.  But we can access the union in a very roundabout way by:

- creating a variable with type `any`
- calling JS `typeof` on that variable, which will return the union of all possible types
- creating a typescript type that uses TS `typeof` to access that union as a type.

```
const x: any = "";

const t = typeof x;

type TypeofTypes = typeof t;
```

This creates

```
type TypeofTypes = "string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w62EEw)

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way I've found so far too.